# How to write every 12th line to a new file

Tags: python, file

I want to select every 12th line in a file and write those lines into a new file. Anyone have a suggestion? I have 126 lines, first 6 lines are header, so I need to select the 7th, 19th and 31st line and so on until end of file is reached. and every 10 lines selected should go into a new file.

The way the code is written I can write one file, say P_1 which is made of 10 (every 12th) lines 7,19,31...,109  I want to make 12 files though.  So the first file is P_1 which starts at 7th line, P_2 would start at 8th line.  How do I loop through to get from 7 to 8 and so on, eventually to line 18?

I would included for i in range to write the new 12 files (will that work?).

for i in range (1,12): 
with open('output%i.txt' %i,'w+') as g: I just dont know how to get the lines to change so they correspond with the correct file. Ya know what I mean?

Thanks again!

Comment: use the modulo operator `%`. specifically: `(line-6) % 12 == 1`

Answer (score 6):

If you have a large file, this approach is good as it doesn't load the whole file into memory. (as `for line in f.readlines()` would)

```
from itertools import islice #used to get the 7th, 19th, etc... lines
import fileinput #to iterate over lines without loading whole file into memoru

with open('output.txt','w+') as g:
    for line in islice(fileinput.input('file.txt'),6,None,12): #start at 6 because iterable 0-indexed, that is the 7th element has index 6
        g.write(line)
```

**OR** (Method pointed out by @Elazar)

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as g, open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in islice(f,6,None,12):
        g.write(line)
```

Comment: Can we just use `with open('file.txt') as f` and pass `f` to `islice` directly here? The whole file won't be loaded into memory at once, right? After all we are using `f` as an `iterator`. Pls correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Satoru.Logic That's true: http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.next, the main reason for using fileinput is so we don't need to have another `with open(...` to load file.txt.

Comment: For Python 2.7+ you can use a single `with` to open both files. See @Elazar's answer

Comment: @gnibbler I never knew this (I've added that option to my answer)

Answer (score 3):

```
with open("input") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if (i-7) % 12 == 0: print line.rstrip("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('newfile.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('input.txt') as infile:
    newfile.writelines(k for i, k in enumerate(infile) if i%12==7)
```

Comment: Quick responses! thanks guys, I will test this out tomorrow when I am in front of python.  I will give you some updates. Not sure what Elazar means by "real world".  It is a script that I will need to use over and over again, it isn't for school or something.

Comment: @user2379814 If so, it *is* a "real world" script. I used an `open()` outside `with` in the first version of this answer. Now this answer is OK, but @HennyH gave a better one.

Answer (score 0):

```
# creating the file as a base for me, you don't need this part
with open('dan.txt','w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(str(i) for i in xrange(1,127)))



# your desired code
with open('dan.txt') as g:
    li = g.readlines()

for i in xrange(6,19):
    with open('P_%d.txt' % (i-5),'w') as f:
        f.writelines(li[x] for x in xrange(i,126,12))
```